# ArrayList<Integer> is outputting the wrong result when using the set method

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
num.add(0);
num.add(0);
num.add(0);
System.out.println(num.set(1, 2));//I don't know why it's outputting 2's down the
                                  //second column
System.out.println("   0  1  2");
int counter1 = 0;
for(int row : num) {
    System.out.println(counter1 + " " + num);
    counter1 += 1;
}
```

I need help figuring out why the 3 by 3 array is outputting 2's down one column.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I want to be able to specify row 0, column 1 with the number 2. However, it changes each row [0,1,2], column 1 with the number 2. I just wanted to change one number.

Comment: You have a List<Integer>. That is a 1D structure. Not a 2D structure. You would need a List<List<Integer>> to have a 2D structure, i.e. a list of rows, where each row has numbers. I suggest you read the javadoc of List to understand what a List is, and the javadoc of its set() method, to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration you are printing the entire `ArrayList` (`num`), instead of just the relevant element (`row`):

```
for (int row : num) {
    System.out.println(counter1 + " " + row);
    // Here ----------------------------^
    counter1 += 1;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. Still, not really clear if this was what was required. Sounds like OP is after double-dimension structure while the current code deals with a single dimension.